# what is difference between probability and probability space?

Tags: probability-theory

I am a beginner in probability and started reading the relative material. I encountered the exercise question "find the probability space for tossing a fair coin till the first head is observed". so, I would like to ask you, are probability and probability space different? If yes, please provide the example with the above as the question.

Comment: A probability is a single number between 0 and 1 and is the chance of occurence of an event. Probability space refers to the events themselves, which are taken into consideration.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code There is a wider notion of *probability*. It is actually a function on *events* that connects each event with a single number belonging to $[0,1]$. This under certain axioms.

Comment: @drhab Wouldn't you call the function a "probability function" and the actual answer the "probability"?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code. The term *probability* is generally used for a special measure. But I admit: one can also speak of *probability measure* (see the answer of @did). And next to that there is of course the probability of a special event, wich is a single number, as you said. I don't exclude that *probability function* is also used, but not by me.

Comment: I think that in very simple words, it means - find each possible event and its probability (and the probabilities should sum up to $1$ of course).

Comment: Hey hello world, I'm editing my answer. Many thanks to @Did

Comment: @helloworld How come you accepted swiftly an answer here given that this answer is still under heavy revision (to the point of being nearly unreadable... but surely I am biased on this?) and that you asked again, two weeks later, nearly the same question?

Comment: @Did Indeed While I was reading about probability at that time, the terminology seemed inconsistent and led to confusion among definitions, which you correctly pointed out in the third comment of that question. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A probability space is a triplet $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$, where $\Omega$ is a set, $\mathcal F$ is a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$, and $P$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$. Thus, a probability is the third element in a triplet defining a probability space.

*Example:* To model one throw of a die, one could use $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\mathcal F=2^\Omega$ and $P:A\mapsto\frac16\#A$ for every $A\subseteq\Omega$.

Comment: could you please explain with an simple example about the probability space?

Comment: As you said that probability space is a triplet, for the given die modelling, how many triplets are possible?

Comment: Triplet: ordered set with three elements. First element: Omega. Second element: F. Third element: P. "how many triplets are possible?" Sorry but what are you talking about?

Comment: Iam actually trying to correlate the triplets here with the 3 dimensional coordinates, What i mean to say is that, as such in the case of 3D coordintes, we can have infinite possible triplets,similarly can I say that the number of triplets possible for a given scenario is equal to the number of elements in the second element "F=2 to the power of omega"

Comment: Here is a suggestion: forget 3 dimensional coordinates and read what I actually wrote.

Answer (score 5):

You're a beginning in probability? In that case, you shouldn't be learning about probability spaces, I think. You should be learning about Kolmogorov axioms, counting techniques, distribution functions, Bayes' Theorem, etc.

Anyway, a probability space is often denoted $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$, a triple of three things:

$\Omega$ is the set of possible outcomes. It is nonempty. Here $\Omega = (H, TH, TTH, TTTH, ...)$

$\mathfrak{F}$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$ that represents "information". The elements of $\mathfrak{F}$ are called "events" meaning we know the probability of any element of $\mathfrak{F}$ (probability of any event). You might want to check [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Discrete_examples) out.

Sometimes, we can choose $\mathfrak{F} = 2^{\Omega}$, meaning we know the probabilities of each of the subsets of $\Omega$. I think we can always choose $\mathfrak{F} = 2^{\Omega}$ if $\Omega$ is countable.

$2^{\Omega}$ then is the largest possible $\mathfrak{F}$.

The smallest possible $\mathfrak{F}$ is $(\emptyset, \Omega)$, meaning you know only that the probability that nothing will happen is zero and that something will happen is one. Meaning, you don't know the probabilities of any of the subsets of $\Omega$ or as Ygritte would say, you know nothing.

$\mathfrak{F}$ has certain properties:

1 $\Omega \in \mathfrak{F}$ Obviously we know, the probability that anything can happen is 1.

2 $A \in \mathfrak{F} \to \Omega$ \ $ A \in \mathfrak{F}$ Obviously, if we know the probability of an event happening, we know the probability that said event doesn't happen. It is obvious that $A \subseteq \Omega$ since $\mathfrak{F}$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$.

3 $A_1, A_2, ... \in \mathfrak{F} \to \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathfrak{F}$. If we know the probabilities of each event $A_1, A_2, ...$, then we know the probability of at least one of them happening but **not** vice-versa.

In our case, here are some possible $\mathfrak{F}$'s (check that the verify the above properties):

$\mathfrak{F} = (\emptyset, \Omega, H, TH \cup TTH \cup TTTH \cup ...)$

$\mathfrak{F} = (\emptyset, \Omega, H \cup TH, TTH \cup TTTH \cup ...)$

$\mathfrak{F} = (\emptyset, \Omega, H \cup TTH, TH \cup TTTH \cup ...)$

$\mathfrak{F} = (\emptyset, \Omega, H \cup TTH \cup TTTTH \cup ..., TH \cup TTTH \cup TTTTTH...)$

and of course

$\mathfrak{F} = (\emptyset, \Omega)$

$\mathfrak{F} = 2^{\Omega}$

Finally, $P$ is the probability measure, which is the method by which you compute the probability of events. It's something like assigning a number (i.e. the probability) to which event.

It has the properties:

1 mapping from $\mathfrak{F} \to [0,1]$ We can't compute the probability of objects not in $\mathfrak{F}$ by definition. Also, there are negative probabilities, but let's just consider $[0,1]$ for now.

2 $P(\Omega) = 1$ by assumption

3 $P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n)$ if $A_1, A_2, ... \in \mathfrak{F}$ and $A_1, A_2, ...$ are pairwise disjoint. If we know the probabilities of each of the pairwise disjoint events $A_1, A_2, ...$, then we know the probability of at least one of them happening **and** vice-versa.

In our case, if we choose $\mathfrak{F} = 2^{\Omega}$, we can say that

$$P(H) = 1/2, P(TH) = 1/4, P(TTH) = 1/8, ...$$ since anything you put inside $P()$ is an element of $\mathfrak{F}$

It can be seen that $$P(H^C) = P(TH \cup TTH \cup TTTH \cup ...)$$

$$= P(TH) + P(TTH) + P(TTTH) + ... = 1/4 + 1/8 + ... = 1/2$$

If we choose $\mathfrak{F} = (\emptyset, \Omega, H \cup TTH, TH \cup TTTH \cup ...)$, then there's no way we can assign a value to $P(TH)$ as $TH$ is not even a valid input for $P()$ since $TH \notin \mathfrak{F}$

It's helpful to consider random variables when explaining probability spaces.

A random variable can be thought of as a payoff of a game.

Formally, it is a mapping from $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. its "preimages" (see examples below) are events (elements of $\mathfrak{F}$)

Say we flip two coins.

Let X be the random variable equal to 1 if the result is two heads and 0 otherwise. So, you gain, say, $1 if the result is two heads and nothing otherwise.

The outcomes that result in $X=1: \ HH$

The outcomes that result in $X=0: \ TH, HT, TT$

Thus, the preimages of X are: $\emptyset, \Omega, HH, TH \cup HT \cup TT$

Now consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$

where

$\Omega = (HH, TH, HT, TT)$

$\mathfrak{F} = (\emptyset, \Omega)$

$X$ is not a "random variable in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$" since some of its preimages are not in $\mathfrak{F}$.

The intuitive explanation: Again, $(\emptyset, \Omega)$ is the smallest possible $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$. So, if $\mathfrak{F} = (\emptyset, \Omega)$, all we know is that $P(HH \cup TH \cup HT \cup TT) = 1$ and $P(\emptyset) = 0$. We have no idea how the game will turn out.

Now what happens if we rigged the game into making sure that the second toss is heads i.e. $HH \cup TH$ will happen? We have $\mathfrak{F_1} = (\emptyset, \Omega, (HH \cup TH), (HT \cup TT))$

$X$ is also not a "random variable in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F_1}, P)$. We don't know the probabilities of all the preimages of $X$ given our information (based on our rigging).

However if we let $Y$ be the random variable equal to 1 if the result is $HH$ or $TH$ and $0$ otherwise, then we have:

The outcomes that result in $Y = 1: (HH, TH)$

The outcomes that result in $Y = 0: (HT, TT)$

$Y$ is a random variable in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F_1}, P)$.

$\mathfrak{F_1}$ represents information on the assumption our rigging will be successful, and since we know how the game will turn out since we have rigged the game to turn up heads on the second toss, we know the probabilities of the preimages of Y: $P(Y = 1) = P(HH, TH) = 1$ and $P(Y = 0) = P(HT, TT) = 0$.

If we know the probability of two heads is $0.5$, then we have $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F_2}, P)$ where $\mathfrak{F_2} = (\emptyset, \Omega, HH, HT \cup TH \cup TT)$.

$X$ is a random variable in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F_2}, P)$.

Of course, $X$ and $Y$ are random variables in $(\Omega, 2^{\Omega}, P)$. If we know the probabilities of all possible events (all subsets of $\Omega$), then know all the probabilities of the preimages of $X$ and $Y$.

Try [this](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/crypto/Overheads/03_prob.pdf) too (Here, $\mathfrak{F}$ always $= 2^{\Omega}$).

[This](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~valko/courses/632/prob_basics.pdf) also.

Comment: thanks for the material provided.Its really helpful.Then reiterating my question, "what could be the probability space for tossing a die till first head is encountered"?

Comment: @helloworld Please ask questions if you want. I know I didn't explain it very well, but I hope to do so if I can.

Comment: @helloworld As for your question, see what I wrote for each part of the $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$. They are on lines 5, 6 and 20 (depending on your screen resolution I guess). Also, I assume you mean coin not die. I'll leave die until 1st, say, "4" is rolled as an exercise :)

Comment: @helloworld response to: As you said that probability space is a triplet, for the given die modelling, how many triplets are possible?, my response: for your game given, only one omega is possible, the script F depends on the events you consider. In your example, there are infinite. Depends on how you group the elements of Omega into events. As for probability measure, one only since the coin is fair. If the coin is not fair, there are infinite ways you can assign probability. You can let the prob of heads be 0.01 or 5/10 or 99/100 or pi/16. Does that answer the question?

Comment: @helloworld Oh I forgot. Welcome to Math SE! If you are satisfied with any answer, please select it as the answer *ahem* mine *ahem* hehehe

Comment: @helloworld I was going over the links I gave you. I think some books use probability space to mean SAMPLE space, which is $\Omega$

Answer (score 3):

I will try to explain it in very simple words:

Finding the probability space means finding each possible event and its probability.

Let's do this with regards to the specific question at hand:

- Event #$1$:

  - You toss the coin once and it lands on head
  - The probability for this event is $\frac{1}{2}$
- Event #$2$:

  - You toss the coin once and it lands on tail
  - You toss the coin again and it lands on head
  - The probability for this event is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$
- $\dots$
- Event #$k$:

  - You toss the coin $k-1$ times and it lands on tail each time
  - You toss the coin again and it lands on head
  - The probability for this event is $\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^{k}}$
- $\dots$

Of course, you have an infinite number of events in this probability space.

You may also assert that the sum of the probabilities of these events is equal to $1$:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\text{number of tosses}=n)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}=1$$